# When I'm trying to access my Linux server using SSH from my winodws machine It's alwasy asking for password though I've copied the key gen in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, rsync, openssh

I'm trying to run ssh from my windows system without asking the password.I've created ssh-keygen and pasted in the authorized_key file in my Linux system. Still it's asking for the password.

```
 RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:Q5TcSuPJUVqNQH9ML9WEFtCMXCY6Zkw2aawp/9A7sKQ.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Comment: This is not related to password. It ask you to add server key to your known hosts file

Comment: Romeo Ninov I added id_rsa.pub file in my Linux server authorized_key file. Still it's asking for the password.

Comment: Do you have enabled the option to authenticate with key in ssh daemon?

Comment: I've added the id_rsa.pub content in my Linux server and also generated one authorised_key file n psted the id_rsa.pub content within it...Not sure if anything else I've to do... Romeo Ninov

Comment: So check `sshd_config`

Comment: In My winodws system ot linux system?..n what exact param I need to check?

Comment: We talk about ssh server. So on linux machine

Comment: PasswordAuthentication yes

Comment: Add in the question the log of entire session when you try to login with some debug information

Comment: Ok.....I'll do that from next time..

Comment: What is the exact name, `authorized_keys` or `authorized_key`?